# Elegant solution to create settings options for a user

Tags: python

I have two setting options. The user can select either `test` or `test1` as settings. If he selects `test`, the method `test` is executed as well as the method `xytest`.

I call the methods `test` and `test1` with a mapping, which also works. However, I still need to call a second method which is `xy<name of mapping method>`. Is there a nicer and more elegant solution how the user can choose between `test` and `test1` and get a different result accordingly? By that I mean isn't there a better solution to get around these if statements?

```
def test():
  return "Hi"

def xytest():
  return "I'm Zoe"

def test1():
  return "Hello"

def xytest1():
  return "I'm Max"

mapping = {
    "test": test,
    "test1": test1,
}



def try_method(option):
  parameter = mapping[option]()
  # How can I shorten both if statements, as in the above call
  if option == 'test': 
    parameter2 = xytest()
  if option == 'test1':
    parameter2 = xytest1()
  # Something like
  # parameter2 = 'xy'+mapping[option]()
  print(parameter)
  print(parameter2)

# the user could only choose between test and test1
try_method('test')
```

Comment: Seems like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/513348). Could you provide some real-world example?

Comment: Not sure why you don't just map to a function that calls both `test` and `xytest` and another that calls both `test1` and `xytest1`

Comment: The problem is the methods are inherently more complex and far more nested than in this example, so two methods must remain.

Comment: The functions return something different than these strings, that is only for illustration so that you can see that these have two different values or all methods return something different.

Comment: I don't know where xy problem should occur here. I'm asking specifically how to avoid this if statement and make exactly such a call with the method test or test1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the `if` clause, i propose to use a slightly different `mapping`. The `mapping` contains a list of functions which can be called depending on the `option` parameter:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def test():
  return "Hi"

def xytest():
  return "I'm Zoe"

def test1():
  return "Hello"

def xytest1():
  return "I'm Max"

mapping = {
    "test": [ test, xytest ],
    "test1": [ test1, xytest1]
}


def try_method(option):

  print(mapping[option][0]())
  print(mapping[option][1]())

# the user could only choose between test and test1
try_method('test')
try_method('test1')
```

Output:

```
Hi
I'm Zoe
Hello
I'm Max
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This has helped me a lot. I appreciate it very much.